# How to assign a local file to the FileField in Django?

Tags: python, django, filefield

I was trying to assign a file from my disk to the FileField, but I have this error:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'open'

My python code:

```
pdfImage = FileSaver()
pdfImage.myfile.save('new', open('mytest.pdf').read())
```

and my models.py

```
class FileSaver(models.Model):

    myfile = models.FileField(upload_to="files/")

    class Meta:
        managed=False
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Django uses it's own [file type](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/#the-file-object) (with a sightly enhanced functionality). Anyway Django's file type works like a [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), so you can simply wrap it around existing file objects to meet the needs of the Django API.

```
from django.core.files import File

local_file = open('mytest.pdf')
djangofile = File(local_file)
pdfImage.myfile.save('new', djangofile)
local_file.close()
```

You can of course decorate the file on the fly by writing the following (one line less):

```
pdfImage.myfile.save('new', File(local_file))
```

Comment: overwriting <type 'file'> is probably a bad idea. Better to use file_

Comment: Just to explain the above comment (I was confused for a bit) Aaron is talking about the symbol `file` (i.e. the name of the variable) rather than the type of argument passed.

Comment: Remember to close both the python file object, _and_ the Django File object.

Comment: If you get a `UnicodeDecodeError`, try open the file in binary mode: `local_file = open("mytest.pdf", "rb")`.

Comment: As the "file" variable was renamed to "local_file" in the answer, @AaronMcMillin ' s comment doesn't make sense anymore.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to open the file, you can also move the file to the media folder and directly set myfile.name with the **relative path to MEDIA_ROOT** :

```py
import os
os.rename('mytest.pdf', '/media/files/mytest.pdf')
pdfImage = FileSaver()
pdfImage.myfile.name = '/files/mytest.pdf'
pdfImage.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to upload a local file in django, you can do this

```
from django.core.files import File

file = open(filepath, 'rb')
file_to_upload = File(file, name=f'{your_desired_name}')
file.close()
```

Now you can pass the file to django rest serializer to upload or whatever your use-case is. If passing this file to serializer, be sure to close it after it has been passed to serializer.

Note: The filepath here can be django's temporary file or any stored file.

Answer (score 2):

if you are getting error like:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position...
```

then you have to open the file in binary mode: `open("mytest.pdf", "rb")`

full example:

```
from django.core.files import File

pdfImage = FileSaver()
pdfImage.myfile.save('new.pdf', File(open('mytest.pdf','rb')))
```