# AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'open' in Django while assigning a local file to the FileField

Tags: python, django, file, filefield

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to assign a local file to the FileField in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501588/how-to-assign-a-local-file-to-the-filefield-in-django)

I was trying to assign a file from my disk to the FileField, but I have this error:

**AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'open'**

My python code:

```
pdfImage = FileSaver()
myPdfFile = open('mytest.pdf')
pdfImage.myfile.save('new', myPdfFile)
```

and my models.py

```
class FileSaver(models.Model):

    myfile = models.FileField(upload_to="files/")

    class Meta:
        managed=False
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same question that you asked an hour ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501588/how-to-assign-a-local-file-to-the-filefield-in-django Is there any specific reason why you are posting it again as a new question?

Comment: Don't repost identical questions an hour apart.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.nitinh.com/2009/02/django-example-filefield-and-imagefield/. You need to pass `save` a Django request.