# Django 2 Saving models.FileField manualy in forms.py

Tags: django, django-forms

My code is:

**models.py**

```
class Claimmessage(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(_('Сообщение'),)


class Claimfile(models.Model):
    claimmessage = models.ForeignKey(Claimmessage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Сообщение рекламации'), )
    attachment = models.FileField(upload_to='claims/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, null=True,)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ClaimCreateForm( forms.Form ):
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,)
    attachments = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))

    def save(self, commit=False):
        message = self.cleaned_data.get("message")
        attachments = self.cleaned_data.get("attachments")

        mess = Claimmessage()
        mess.text = message
        mess.save()

        for f in attachments:
            Claimfile.objects.create(claimmessage=message, attachment=f)
```

**views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClaimCreateForm(request.POST, request.FILES,)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save()

            return redirect('claim_details', claim_id=obj.pk)
    else:
        form = ClaimCreateForm()
```

And I've got

> AttributeError at /ru/claims/400002013/create/ 'bytes' object has no
>   attribute '_committed'

How can I save file object in form.save() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this block of code

```
for f in attachments:
    Claimfile.objects.create(claimmessage=message, attachment=f)
```

with the following

```
for f in attachments:
    claimfile = Claimfile(claimmessage=mess)
    claimfile.attachment.save(f.name, f, save=True)
```

See the explaination [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3502356/5840704)

Comment: **Some update**: `attachments = self.cleaned_data.get("attachments")` do not return iteratable object. You have to override widget class, or simply use this solution instead all of this: (https://github.com/Chive/django-multiupload)